# Map url link with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make this url map:

http://www.site.com/blog

http://www.site.com/blog/category/showcase

Something like this, is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/category/showcase
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://www.site.com/blog/category/showcase [R=301,L]
```

Any idea about that?

Comment: Are there more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava here is the .htaccess http://sharetext.org/da3y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your 301 before internal rewrites. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^$ category/showcase [R=301,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```